# How can I run an npm script installed in the root of a learn repo, from a child package?

Tags: npm, lerna

For instance, I want to run jest tests for **one** of my packages.

I set up the test script in the child `package.json`:

```
"test" : "jest"
```

However when I got to the package directory and run:

```
npm test
```

I get:

```
sh: jest: command not found
```

This makes sense because I've only installed `jest` in the root package since it is a dev dependency.

What do I need to do to make the npm package `jest` available in the child packages?

Comment: Does this help "npx lerna run test --scope pkg1" ?

Answer (score 0):

We're using an npm package called env-cmd https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd to run scripts from root level in packages.

our root package.json looks something like this:

```
  {
    "name": "@myAwesomeApp/root",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
      "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
      "lerna": "^5.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      [...]
    },
    "workspaces": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "scripts": {
      "internal:warning": "echo \"\n\t\\\\033[32m! ANY NOTIFICATION !\n\"",
      "jest": "npm run internal:warning && env-cmd --silent  lerna run test"
    }
  }
```